# f:ajax execute="@this" does not fire listener method

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

In the following case, it never calling the listener method.

### TestBean.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private int score1;
    private int score2;
    private int score3;

    public void resetPage(){
        score1 = 35;
        score2 = 35;
        score3 = 35;
    }

    public int getScore1() {
        return score1;
    }

    public void setScore1(int score1) {
        this.score1 = score1;
    }

    public int getScore2() {
        return score2;
    }

    public void setScore2(int score2) {
        this.score2 = score2;
    }

    public int getScore3() {
        return score3;
    }

    public void setScore3(int score3) {
        this.score3 = score3;
    }

}
```

### requirements.xhtml

```
<h:form id="requirementsForm" prependId="false">
    <h:messages style="color: #FF0000; font-size: 13px; margin: 10px; white-space: nowrap;" /> 
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td> Score 1: </td>
        <td>
            <h:inputText value="#{testBean.score1}" required="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Score 2: </td>
        <td>
            <h:inputText value="#{testBean.score2}" required="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Score 3: </td>
        <td>
            <h:inputText value="#{testBean.score3}" required="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <h:commandLink style="margin-left: 1px;" styleClass="submitLink">
             <img src="#{request.contextPath}/circuit_images/refresh.png" />
                  <f:ajax execute="@this"
                          render="@form" 
                          listener="#{testBean.resetPage}"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

I know the default for execute is @this,
I removed it & tried still same problem.
It never call testBean#resetPage() method.

```
          <f:ajax execute="@this"
                  render="@form" 
                  listener="#{testBean.resetPage}"/>
```

When i update execute="@form" it works.

```
          <f:ajax execute="@form"
                  render="@form" 
                  listener="#{testBean.resetPage}"/>
```

The form has some input fields with required & other validations.
But for reset button, i don't want those validations to process.

i have added immediate="true" on both `<h:commandLink> & <f:ajax>`, It didn't worked.
I am using JSF 2.2 & Tomcat 6.0.35.

I also refered to 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf 
& 
http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/eventlistener/ResetInputAjaxActionListener.html
i could not able to resolve this.

Comment: Why exactly are you using `prependId="false"` in the form?

Comment: To avoid the form id being prefix to every field id, & also to avoid too long id to all elements, when i need to use them in javascript or JQuery, everytime i need to escape the default prepender **'\\:'** .

Comment: can you try this for button.execute="@form" and immediate="true".

Comment: for button or link , actually if i use execute="@form" with immediate=true, it is calling the method, but if i submit the form with empty values, i still see empty field validation errors after the method call, though the method updating them with some default values.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade your jsf version to 2.1. Only Tomcat8 supports javaee7, and jsf 2.2 is javaee7 specific.

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container. It will never support JavaEE, in whatever version.

Comment: Than what do you understand from and i qoute: "The Apache Tomcat Project is proud to announce the release of version 8.0.3 (beta) of Apache Tomcat. Tomcat 8 is aligned with Java EE 7. In addition to supporting updated versions of the Java EE specifications, Tomcat 8 includes a number of improvements compared to Tomcat 7. " taken from http://tomcat.apache.org/

Comment: Since we're on SO, let me quote the [JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info): "JSF 2.2 requires a minimum of Servlet 3.0, because of the new file upload component which is internally using the standard Servlet 3.0 API without the need for 3rd party libraries. [...] Examples of Servlet 3.0 containers are Tomcat 7.0.x". While you *are* correct that tomcat-6 will not support JSF-2.2 (fully), your reasoning is flawed: tomcat is "aligned" to JEE7, which means they support parts of it. And JSF-2.2 is an independent specification that is *included* (not specific) to JEE7.

Comment: When i said specific, i meant it wont run on anything lower that javaee7, and javaee7 will never run on a standard installation of tomcat7 or lower, because i've read on the documentation that tomcat runs javaee6 under the hood even though your webapp is configured for javaee7. It was some time ago, but if i'll find the link i'll post it. As a simple test try creating a web apllication in netbeans and choose Tomcat as server, it will force you to use java6 and jsf2.1 as a max.

Comment: If you're unclear on how to run JSF-2.2 on Tomcat-7, please post a question. It has nothing to do with the JEE7 specification other than that JEE7 includes parts of the stuff you need for JSF-2.2, too.